# Solve interesting exponential equation in terms of x

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, exponential-distribution

I am having difficulty solving this equation in terms of $x$

$y =\dfrac{x^x}{x^{x^{\frac{x}{k}}}}$

I have been able to re-arrange exponents into the following:

$x^x x^{-\sqrt[k]{x^x}} $

$x^{x - \sqrt[k]{x^x}} $

$xe^{x\ln x - \sqrt[k]{x^x}-\ln x} $

I am not too certain how to proceed. I have read about the Lambert $W$ function, but I don't know how to manipulate variables to reach that point.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't think this is possible to solve. There are too many $x$'s

Comment: I doubt very much that there is a closed-form solution. It is very unlikely that LambertW will help here.

Comment: $e^{\ln(x)e^{\ln(x)\frac{x}{k}}}y=e^{\ln(x)x}$. This equation is an equation in dependence of $e^{\ln(x)e^{\ln(x)\frac{x}{k}}}$ and $e^{\ln(x)x}$, algebraic over C. Because the terms $e^{\ln(x)e^{\ln(x)\frac{x}{k}}},e^{\ln(x)x}$ are algebraically independent, we don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by only elementary operations (means elementary functions).

Comment: Functions similar to the one you described usually don't have easy inverses. E.g., f(x)=x^(x^x) doesn't have an inverse in terms of common functions like how f(x)=x^x does.